# simple regex in php, formatting decimal number

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert numbers to have .00 after them, but only if the number is an integer, or it has just 1 number after the decimal point, like so:

```
1.4 = 1.40
45 = 45.00
34.77 = 34.77
```

What reg exp to use for this simple case?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

Read more at [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).  You don't need to determine if a number is an integer or not -- as long as it's a number, it will be formatted to two decimal places.

If you'd like the thousands separator, change the last parameter to `','`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [printf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) or [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
printf("%01.2f", '34.77');
$formatted_num = sprintf("%01.2f", '34.77');
```

Comment: Good call -- runs about 40% faster than `number_format()` if you don't need that thousands separator.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PHP's built-in function [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

You can pass it a variable and it'll format it to the correct decimal places

```
    $number = 20;
    if (is_int($number)) {
        $number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

read [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 0.00638835;

$avg = sscanf($num,"%f")[0] /100;

echo sprintf("%.10f", $avg);

result 0.0000638835
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing and how this works

Comment: sscanf — Parses input from a string according to a format

Comment: The function sscanf() is the input analog of printf(). sscanf() reads from the string str and interprets it according to the specified format, which is described in the documentation for sprintf().

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.