# Covert digit to x.xx format in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple regex in php, formatting decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044815/simple-regex-in-php-formatting-decimal-number)

How to convert a digit in x format to x.xx format in php?
example : 
I have a number 5. Need to convert to 5.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$n = 5;
$n = number_format($n, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `number_format()`:

```
$your_number = 5;

echo number_format($your_number, 2); // displays 5.00
```

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

```
number_format('your digit', 2 or 1, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $number = 125

 $no = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');


 output = 125.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 5;
$x = sprintf('%.2f', $x);
echo $x;
```